# Copying the result of a find operation in shell

Tags: shell, find

I want to find a file, and simultaneously copy it to another directory like this:

```
cp (find . -name myFile | tail -n 1) dir/to/copy/to
```

But this says unexpected token `find'

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is purpose of `tail -n 1` ?

Comment: it gets me a bunch of results, but I only need the last one

Comment: So you want to copy **only** last file to `dir/to/copy/to`

Comment: yeah, the last result of the find op

Answer (score 1):

You may use a pipeline:

```
find . -name 'myFile' -print0 | tail -z -n 1 | xargs -0 -I {} cp {} /dir/to/copy/to/
```

Using `-print0` option to address filenames with whitespace, glob characters

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name 'myFile' -print0 | tail  -n 1 | xargs -0 -I {} cp {} /dir/to/copy/to/
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options are available-

## Appended the missing $() - to evaluate command (not sure the purpose of tail command, only required for samefile in multiple directories)

1. cp **$**(find . -name myFile | tail -n 1) dir/to/copy/to
2. find . -name myFile -type f -exec cp {} dir/to/copy/to  \;